# Include information about the retag tag in floating tag help

Tags: feature-request

Currently when a user goes to tag a post they are presented with this:

[image: picture of how to tag tooltip on ask a question page]

This doesn't mention what to do if they can't find a tag for the series they are looking for. On a normal stack exchange site, this would usually mean that this is a topic that is implicitly not allowed. However, our site constantly has new tags being created for new/old series that haven't had questions before.

For this, we've made [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) for users that don't have the privilege to create tags.

However, new users don't know to use this tag, and we don't give them a notice telling them what tag to use. Then they put any tag they can find. We have the retag tag so we will always catch these instances where the tag needs to be edited. We might not notice that the wrong tag is used if they choose a random tag.

We have mentioned the retag tag in the help center and in the tour page, but these aren't always used by new users. I'd like to have a line added to the tooltip screenshotted above with something along the lines of:

> use the [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) tag if the series or tag can't be found, and someone with the tagging privilege will retag it for you